# C++ is that possible to initialize base class' base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying out the below snippet,

```
#include <string>

class A {
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    A(std::string name):name(){}
};

class B: public A {
public:
    B() : A("B") {}
};

class C: public B {
public:
    C(): A("C"){} //<-- this is not allowed, but I want to make C has its own name
};
```

Obviously, this is not allowed, what is the best way I can achieve this?

Comment: just give `B` a `protected` constructor that lets derived classes set the name? but this might be an X/Y problem, so perhaps you should explain what problem you are trying to solve with this constant per-class data copied into each instance, and there's probably a better way.

Comment: One more option would be just setting `A::name` again in C's constructor body: `C() { name = "C";}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewriting `B`'s constructor

```
B(const std::string& name = "B") : A(name) {}
```

is one way. Here I'm equipping it with a default value, so it still acts as the default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to use virtual inheritance:

```
class A {
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    A(std::string name):name(){}
};

class B: public virtual A { // note the "virtual" keyword here
public:
    B() : A("B") {}
};

class C: public B {
public:
    C(): A("C") {} 
};
```

This does what you asked for, but I am not sure this is what you need.

You should consider just adding a separate constructor to `class B` (probably `protected` one) that does such initialization.

Comment: Virtual inheritance is a **design decision**, not a coding hack. It changes the meaning of the class hierarchy, so it's not an appropriate workaround for an erroneous constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can like that,

```
#include <string>

class A {
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    A(std::string name) : name(name){} // also here a mistake 
};

class B: public A {
public:
    B() : A("B") {}
protected:
    B(std::string str) : A(str) {}
};

class C: public B {
public:
    C(): B("C"){}
};
```

The reason why I have placed `B(std::string str)` in the protected area is only derived class can access that area but the clients do not. I think that you want that if the class created from client base class is named as A.